# clipboard problem with a few questions in a list

Tags: c#, clipboard

**MY PROBLEM**
I have a program with a lot of questions in a list. I want to get a return on that questions with a clipboard. But i have more than 50 questions in my program and sometimes i doesnt get a return on some questions in my list how do i fix that?

**THIS IS MY CODE**

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    //check if current operation is a clipboard
    if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
    {

        //then we use a try catch block so if 
        //anything wrong happens in Clipboard.GetText() our program wont crash
        try
        {
            //with foreach we go through all our questions
            foreach (string question in questionList)
                //with foreach we go through all our questions

                {
                //and we check if clapboarded text is matches with our question
                if (Clipboard.GetText() == "When a computer is being assembled, which action can be taken to help eliminate cable clutter within a computer case?")
                {
                    notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
                    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "When a computer is being assembled, which action can be taken to help eliminate cable clutter within a computer case?";
                    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Install a modular power supply.*";
                    notifyIcon2.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
                    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: Please clarify your intentions, to me it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i want that  a windows notification only pops-up if i highlight and copied the question on the answer that is copied with ctrl+ c. but i put a lot of questions in a list and sometimes i don't get a return. I don't know how i can fix that

Comment: My guess - @TeunvandenBroek - is working on some Test/Exam app. And if the user/examinee tries to copy the question (hence "the clipboard") and then would like to Online search the question (so as to cheat). He wants to block that.

Comment: Do you get any errors or does the code run smoothly but just gives no return? If this is  the case, I think `Clipboard.GetText() == question` this condition is not met.

Comment: @TeunvandenBroek - If my above guess is nearly true - why dont you make the Questions in your App (Not Selectable). I guess you used TextBoxes/RichtextBoxes to show the Questions (seems like winforms app to me).

Comment: Another point you need to consider is that - what stops your user to copy the question partially (that way you clipboard is not same as question string) and then Cheat.

Comment: i editied my code maybe you see the issue now?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, so I'm pretty sure sometimes one of your two conditions is not met.

```
const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 36;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        //check if current operation is a clipboard
        if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Clipboard.GetText() == "123")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Clipboard.GetText());
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
   }
```